# Are the conditions in ConditionalExpression necessary or sufficient?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, conditional

I computed a limit and obtained it in the form of a `ConditionalExpression` (see below). Substituting the variables with numerical values in the resulting formula gave the same result as the limit calculated **after** doing such substitutions. However, for this given set of substitutions, one of the conditions was False and yet the formula matched the limit value calculated after the substitutions. Does this mean that the conditions are sufficient but not necessary?

[image]